# How to use ODATA skip and top on Power Automate SharePoint GetItems?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I need to get all the items of a SharePoint list and send as JSON
But the default is 100
If I set a larger number like 10000 it gives this error on the flow:

```
The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.
```

So I am trying to get it in batches of 350 items.

But how can I use the Filter Query to start at a position `x` and return `y` items?

I tried

```
$skip eq 350
```

But this error occurs:

> Column 'skip' does not exist

[image: Get items]

Comment: https://ashiqf.com/2020/06/16/batch-sharepoint-requests-get-post-patch-delete-in-powerautomate-and-ms-graph/

You will have to use the "Send HTTP request to Sharepoint" Action in order to achieve batching

Comment: Filter Query is used in order to cut down List Items.
You will have to write a Statement that would have a true or false outcome based on a column of the list item, and you would get the list items back.

Comment: Get more data, items, or records by using pagination in Azure Logic Apps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exceed-default-page-size-with-pagination

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has 2 layers to it.

1. To increase the number of items returned by the Get Items Actions from Sharepoint  you need click on the **three dots on the left side of the action**, and then go to **Settings** and you will see the image below, then set the size to 5000, that means your Get Items action will now return a maximum of 5000 items.
2. $top and $skip - I am not too confident what you are trying to do with this but perhaps share a bit more context, it sounds like you want to build a dynamic pagination ? Please explain this part unless the first point already achieve what you were aiming for

[image]

Comment: Good direction. What happened is that a user created a Power App that saves data on a Sharepoint List and it has more than 8000 items. So I am having difficulty to read those items due to those limitations.

Comment: @Tony If you add a Column (e.g ItemNumber) of Type AutoNumber and use Odata filter to return a set bound by a lower value and an upper value each time you make the call, would this not solve your issue ? For example the first time your Get Items runs you return items with ItemNumber lt 5000 and second time it runs you return items with itemNumber gt 4999 .. would this help you ?

Comment: Good Idea. That SharePoint List was created by a third party. Perhaps I can ask them to add this ItemNumber Column of Type AutoNumber